# pythonic way to identify a local file or a url

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, filesystems

URL

```
http://www.example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

LOCAL FILES

```
file:///example.html
/home/user/example.html
./home/user/example.html
.dir/data/example.html
```

Consider above input and identify whether given input string is local regular file or a URL?

What i have Tried

```
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def is_local(_str):
    if os.path.exists(path1):
        return True
    elif urlparse(_str).scheme in ['','file']:
        return True
    return False
```

Call

```
is_local('file:///example.html')     # True
is_local('/home/user/example.html')  # True
is_local('./home/user/example.html') # True
is_local('.dir/data/example.html')   # True

is_local('http://www.example.com')   # False
is_local('www.example.com')          # True
is_local('http://example.com')       # False
is_local('https://example.com')      # False
```

Is there any pythonic way to identify a file is local or an URL without using urllib?

Comment: `www.example.com` is not a URL but it may be a local file. Likewise, `file:///example.html` is a URL pointing to a local file. The question is not well defined.

Comment: @DYZ yes that may be possible is there any other pythonic way to do that without urllib

Comment: Do _what_? As I said, your question is asked incorrectly.

Comment: @DYZ yes I have modified question

Comment: Are the local files actually files or just hypothetical paths?  If they are files you might use use `os.path.exists()` and if not assume it is a remote file.

Comment: @JonSG That's not true. `file:///example.html` is a local file but `os.path.exists()` would not recognize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of `urllib.parse.urlpath` and `os.path.exists`. The first extracts a file path from the URL, whilst the second checks if the path actually refers to a file.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from os.path import exists

def is_local(url):
    url_parsed = urlparse(url)
    if url_parsed.scheme in ('file', ''): # Possibly a local file
        return exists(url_parsed.path)
    return False
```